# hide link image if the link itself is using jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, html, hide

there is a link and right next to it is a link image embedded.
Like 'driving direction + car image"'
if there is no 'driving direction' text for link, hide the care image icon embedded..
How do you do that in jquery??
please someone?

```
<span class="website">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit My Website</a>
</span> 
<img class="websiteimage" src="/Style Library/Images/design/icons/icon-www.png" alt="WebSite" />
```

so basically check if a tag has any text in it and if its empty hide the img tag embedded pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea if this works, but here's what I would try:

```
$('img').each(function() {
  if ($(this).prev('span.website').find('a').text() == '') {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: You are my hero of the day! :D

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd wrap the entire thing in a div or span to give it some sort of connection.

```
<div class="websiteblock">
    <span class="website">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit My Website</a>
    </span> 
    <img class="websiteimage" src="/Style Library/Images/design/icons/icon-www.png" alt="WebSite" />
</div>
```

Then you can do this:

```
$("div.websiteblock").each(
    function(index, element)
    {
        if ($(element).find("span.website a").text() == "")
            $(element).find("img.websiteimage").hide();
        else
            $(element).find("img.websiteimage").show();
    }
);
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/tomtheman5/vJYhK/

This answer is assuming that you're going to have multiple sets of these link/image pairs. If that assumption is incorrect, just ignore me ;)

Comment: I think `element` is a jQuery object to begin with.